# How can I configure BlueStacks to have Android use dark mode?

Tags: bluestacks, dark-mode

How can I configure [BlueStacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) to have Android use dark mode?

On Android 10 I can use:

[image: and]

but I can't see the option on Android on BlueStacks:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't.

BlueStacks 4.2 bases on Android Nougat - also known as Android 7.x and therefore there is no Dark Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the best solution, but if you are on Windows 7 or 10 (the script was only tested out on those, perhaps it works with other Windows versions newer than 7), by using this autohotkey script, written by teadrinker and other contributors, you will be able to draw multiple inverted color rectangles on the screen (as seen with the 1 and 2 regions in the 2 images below):

```
/*
This script works on Windows 10 with 64 and 32 bit AHK
and on Windows 7 with 64 bit AHK (but not 32 bit), if DWM is turned on (Aero theme).

Use Shift + LButton hotkey to select a new area on the screen, where colors will be inverted
Use Shift + RButton hotkey to delete the previously selected area
Use F9 hotkey to hide/show selected areas and turn off/on Shift + LButton and Shift + RButton hotkeys
*/

/*
; try uncommenting this block, if the scrit doesn't work with some needed windows

If !RegExMatch(DllCall("GetCommandLine", "Str"), " /restart(?!\S)") {
   If (A_PtrSize = 8)
      RunWait "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkeyU64_UIA.exe" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
   Else If A_IsUnicode
      RunWait "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkeyU32_UIA.exe" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
   Else
      RunWait "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkeyA32_UIA.exe" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
}
*/

#NoEnv
#UseHook
SetWinDelay 0
SetBatchLines -1
toggle := true
DllCall("Dwmapi\DwmIsCompositionEnabled", "UIntP", bool)
if !bool {
   MsgBox, 64, DWM, DWM is turned off, this script will not work. Choose the Aero theme and launch the script again!
   ExitApp
}

F9::
   toggle := !toggle
   Magnifier.ToggleShow()
Return

#If toggle
+LButton::
SelectNewArea() {
   Magnifier.stop := true
   area := SelectedArea.Start(0x82FFC800)
   if !(area.w > 10 && area.h > 10)
      Return
   timer := ObjBindMethod(Magnifier, "CreateMagnifier", area)
   SetTimer, % timer, -10
}

+RButton::
DeleteMagnifierUnderMouse() {
   DllCall("GetCursorPos", "Int64P", POINT)
   for k, gui in Magnifier.GUIs {
      if DllCall("PtInRect", "Ptr", gui.area.pRect, "Int64", POINT) {
         Gui, % gui.hGui . ":Destroy"
         break
      }
   }
}

class SelectedArea
{
   Start(colorARGB) {
      area := {x: 0, y: 0, w: 0, h: 0}
      this.ReplaceSystemCursors("IDC_CROSS")
      this.Select(area, colorARGB)
      this.ReplaceSystemCursors("")
      Return area
   }
   
   Select(area, colorARGB) {
      this.hGui := this.CreateSelectionGui(colorARGB)
      Hook := new this.WindowsHook(WH_MOUSE_LL := 14, ObjBindMethod(this, "LowLevelMouseProc"))
      KeyWait, LButton
      Hook := ""
      WinGetPos, x, y, w, h
      Gui, Destroy
      for k in area
         area[k] := %k%
   }
   
   CreateSelectionGui(colorARGB) {
      Gui, New, +hwndhGui +Alwaysontop -Caption +LastFound +ToolWindow +E0x20 -DPIScale
      WinSet, Transparent, % colorARGB >> 24
      Gui, Color, % Format("{:X}", colorARGB & 0xFFFFFF)
      Return hGui
   }
   
   ReplaceSystemCursors(IDC = "")
   {
      static IMAGE_CURSOR := 2, SPI_SETCURSORS := 0x57
           , SysCursors := { IDC_APPSTARTING: 32650
                           , IDC_ARROW      : 32512
                           , IDC_CROSS      : 32515
                           , IDC_HAND       : 32649
                           , IDC_HELP       : 32651
                           , IDC_IBEAM      : 32513
                           , IDC_NO         : 32648
                           , IDC_SIZEALL    : 32646
                           , IDC_SIZENESW   : 32643
                           , IDC_SIZENWSE   : 32642
                           , IDC_SIZEWE     : 32644
                           , IDC_SIZENS     : 32645 
                           , IDC_UPARROW    : 32516
                           , IDC_WAIT       : 32514 }
      if !IDC
         DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", "UInt", SPI_SETCURSORS, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 0)
      else {
         hCursor := DllCall("LoadCursor", "Ptr", 0, "UInt", SysCursors[IDC], "Ptr")
         for k, v in SysCursors {
            hCopy := DllCall("CopyImage", "Ptr", hCursor, "UInt", IMAGE_CURSOR, "Int", 0, "Int", 0, "UInt", 0, "Ptr")
            DllCall("SetSystemCursor", "Ptr", hCopy, "UInt", v)
         }
      }
   }
   
   LowLevelMouseProc(nCode, wParam, lParam) {
      static WM_MOUSEMOVE := 0x200, WM_LBUTTONUP := 0x202
           , coords := [], startMouseX, startMouseY, timer
      if !timer
         timer := ObjBindMethod(this, "LowLevelMouseProc", "timer", "", "")
      if (nCode = "timer") {
         while coords[1] {
            point := coords.RemoveAt(1)
            mouseX := point[1], mouseY := point[2]
            x := startMouseX < mouseX ? startMouseX : mouseX
            y := startMouseY < mouseY ? startMouseY : mouseY
            w := Abs(mouseX - startMouseX)
            h := Abs(mouseY - startMouseY)
            try Gui, % this.hGui . ":Show", x%x% y%y% w%w% h%h% NA
         }
      }
      else {
         if (wParam = WM_LBUTTONUP)
            startMouseX := startMouseY := ""
         if (wParam = WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
            mouseX := NumGet(lParam + 0, "Int")
            mouseY := NumGet(lParam + 4, "Int")
            if (startMouseX = "") {
               startMouseX := mouseX
               startMouseY := mouseY
            }
            coords.Push([mouseX, mouseY])
            SetTimer, % timer, -10
         }
         Return DllCall("CallNextHookEx", "Ptr", 0, "Int", nCode, "UInt", wParam, "Ptr", lParam)
      }
   }

   class WindowsHook {
      __New(type, callBack, isGlobal := true) {
         this.BoundCallback := new this.BoundFuncCallback(callBack, 3, "Fast")
         this.hHook := DllCall("SetWindowsHookEx", "Int", type, "Ptr", this.BoundCallback.addr
                                                 , "Ptr", !isGlobal ? 0 : DllCall("GetModuleHandle", "UInt", 0, "Ptr")
                                                 , "UInt", isGlobal ? 0 : DllCall("GetCurrentThreadId"), "Ptr")
      }
      __Delete() {
         DllCall("UnhookWindowsHookEx", "Ptr", this.hHook)
         this.BoundCallback := ""
      }

      class BoundFuncCallback
      {
         __New(BoundFuncObj, paramCount, options := "") {
            this.pInfo := Object( {BoundObj: BoundFuncObj, paramCount: paramCount} )
            this.addr := RegisterCallback(this.__Class . "._Callback", options, paramCount, this.pInfo)
         }
         __Delete() {
            ObjRelease(this.pInfo)
            DllCall("GlobalFree", "Ptr", this.addr, "Ptr")
         }
         _Callback(Params*) {
            Info := Object(A_EventInfo), Args := []
            Loop % Info.paramCount
               Args.Push( NumGet(Params + A_PtrSize*(A_Index - 2)) )
            Return Info.BoundObj.Call(Args*)
         }
      }
   }
}

class Magnifier
{
   static GUIs := []
   CreateMagnifier(area) {
      static onExitSet := false
      this.show := true
      (!this.onDestroy && this.onDestroy := ObjBindMethod(this, "WM_DESTROY"))
      if !this.GUIs.Count() {
         this.MagInitialize()
         OnMessage(0x0002, this.onDestroy)
      }
      (!onExitSet && OnExit( ObjBindMethod(this, "Clear"), onExitSet := true ))
      Gui := new this.MagGui(area)
      this.GUIs[Gui.hGui] := Gui
      this.stop := false
      this.MainLoop()
   }
   
   MagInitialize() {
      if !this.hLib := DllCall("LoadLibrary", "str", "Magnification.dll") {
         MsgBox, 16, Error, Failed to load Magnification.dll
         Return
      }
      Return DllCall("Magnification\MagInitialize")
   }
   
   Clear() {
      if !this.hLib
         Return
      DllCall("Magnification\MagUninitialize")
      DllCall("FreeLibrary", "Ptr", this.hLib)
      this.hLib := ""
      OnMessage(0x0002, this.onDestroy, 0)
   }
   
   MainLoop() {
      while !this.stop {
         for k, gui in this.GUIs
            this.Update(gui)
      }
   }
   
   Update(gui) {
      area := gui.area
      params := A_PtrSize = 8 ? ["Ptr", area.pRect] : ["Int", area.x, "Int", area.y, "Int", area.r, "Int", area.b]
      DllCall("Magnification\MagSetWindowSource", "Ptr", gui.hMag, params*)
      if !DllCall("IsWindowVisible", "Ptr", gui.hGui)
         try Gui, % gui.hGui . ":Show", % "NA x" . area.x . " y" . area.y . " w" . area.w . " h" . area.h
   }
   
   ToggleShow(mode := "toggle") {
      static areas := []
      Switch mode {
         case "toggle":
            this.show := !this.show
            if (this.show && areas.Count()) {
               timer := ObjBindMethod(this, "ToggleShow", "timer")
               SetTimer, % timer, 100
            }
            if !this.show {
               this.stop := true
               Sleep 100
               for k, gui in this.GUIs
                  areas.Push(gui.area)
               this.GUIs := []
               this.Clear()
            }
         case "timer":
            timer := ObjBindMethod(this, "CreateMagnifier", areas.Pop())
            SetTimer, % timer, -10
            if !areas.Count()
               SetTimer,, Delete
      }
   }

   WM_DESTROY() {
      if !this.GUIs.HasKey(A_Gui)
         Return
      this.GUIs.Delete(A_Gui)
      if !this.GUIs.Count() {
         this.stop := true
         this.Clear()
      }
   }
   
   class MagGui
   {
      __New(area) {
         this.area := area
         area.r := area.x + area.w
         area.b := area.y + area.h
         this.area.SetCapacity("RECT", 16)
         this.area.pRect := this.area.GetAddress("RECT")
         for k, v in ["x", "y", "r", "b"]
            NumPut(area[v], this.area.pRect + 4*(k - 1), "UInt")
         this.CreateGui()
      }
      
      __Delete() {
         try Gui, % this.hGui . ":Destroy"
      }
      
      CreateGui() {
         static MS_INVERTCOLORS := 0x0004
              , exStyles := (WS_EX_TRANSPARENT := 0x00000020)
                          | (WS_EX_COMPOSITED  := 0x02000000)
                          | (WS_EX_LAYERED     := 0x00080000)
         
         area := this.area         
         Gui, New, +hwndhGui -Caption -DPIScale +AlwaysOnTop +Owner +E%exStyles%
         Gui, Margin, 0, 0
         Gui, Add, Custom, % "hwndhMag ClassMagnifier +" . MS_INVERTCOLORS . " w" . area.w . " h" . area.h
         this.hGui := hGui, this.hMag := hMag
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Here's a short video of it, but in this instance it was used only one rectangle:
https://streamable.com/m6ni9j

Please read the start of the script to see how to use it.

You can further modify the script and make itself turn off / on when certain things show up on the bluestacks android screen, but you'll have to do your own research on how to do that.

[Here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=100121) is the thread where the script was taken from.